# react post request after get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The scenario..

- user clicks on a button and after this, it should make POST request to store data on the server.
- before making POST request, GET request is necessary to fetch some partial data, because POST request needs this data.

Can the above be made with react hooks ? as far as I understand, for POST requests, `useEffect` doesn't get used. so The only good way is to create a service or function which won't be a HOOK  ?

Comment: If you just want to make some API calls on click of a button , then `useEffect` is not needed here . Because to use `useEffect` in this case on click of a button you need to update state --> and that state should be part of the `useEffect` dependency array so that the useEffect gets triggered which seems like an overkill in this situation .

Comment: These questions arise because I don't understand if POST request is presumed to be side-effect or not .

Comment: @ggorlen yeah, it's required to set state after the post request, but if I follow what you just said, then when user clicks on a button, i should have another variable which gets changed in order to make sure `useEffect` runs again. makes sense ?

Comment: @ggorlen, What I don't understand is this... for GET, there's no need to set anything , but after POST, there's need to call `setState`. Now,  we call `side effect` to something that changes something outside its local environment. So wherever I write `POST` request, when it's done, i have to set some state, so this causes `side effect`. So this should be in useEffect. where is my logic wrong ?

Comment: @ggorlen I don't mean `side effect` on back-end.  Here is what I call `side effect.`. After the post request is done, I have to update the dom, which means i have to call the function which I created with `useState`.  This all means that in whichever function I call post request, that function is a side effect, because after finishing POST request, it has to call state changing function. So this is what I don't understand, why can POST request be written without  using `useEffect` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232741/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-ggorlen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be much of use to create a normal hook / custom hook for this, if that's what you are looking for, as they are used for different things.

Instead, it can be something as simple as the following:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()

   fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
    .then(result => {
        // Make post request
        fetch(url, {
           method: "POST",
           body: JSON.stringify(result)
        })
       .then(data => {
        // do what you need with the data from the post request
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a Hook. useEffect is just a function why will it not allow POST. I have done POST after GET from within useEffect to call CouchDB APIs